# Instagram API Tags Recent media not returning posts of private followers

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

We have an approved app for public_content on Instagram's API.  But would like to confirm expected behavior after the latest API changes.

Previously (prior 2016 API update), using a user authenticated token and this endpoint /tags/[tag-name]/media/recent, we could fetch all the posts with a given hashtags from public users as well as private users, given they were followers of the authenticated account.  Meaning, if you could log into your IG account and see that user's media, than our app would be able to grab that media as well through the API using your authenticated user token.

Recently ( start of 2017? ), we started noticing that the returned media doesn't always include the private users that are your followers.  We can still get all the public user hashtagged content, but the private user's content was hit or miss.  And we can't seem to figure out any pattern or rule to it.

Has anyone else faced this issue?  Does anyone know what the official stance is from Instagram as it relates to a private user's photos who follow a certain account, and your app has that account's authenticated token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get anything from private followers even if the user you're logged in as can see them from the client.

This was done because, in the past, some applications were getting the media from private followers via the API and saving them locally. Then, these applications were not properly protecting these private images from search engines and web crawlers. **User's complained about their private images showing up on Google images and so, here we are.**

You also can't see bio or the follower count of private users even if the user you've authenticated with can see them in the application. Basically, only the public-facing information about private users can be accessed with the API regardless of who you've authenticated with via the API. That means only the profile picture and username can be accessed.